# Deleted home folder on ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: home-directory

I was tired two days ago and I accidently deleted my home folder on my VPS. I just rmed it like a retard. Don't ask me why. It's the first time something like that happened in 3 years. **I do not care about the data lost, I had nothing important in my home folder.** So I don't care about any kind of recovery.

So I created a new home folder with "sudo mkdir /home/spazmic", then I "sudo chown spazmic:spazmic /home/spazmic" to give folder rights to my user. I still had access to the VPS, so I copied back the RSA key to my authorized keys folder to be able to reconnect so right now everything is acting like this incident never happened. When I "cd", I go back to my home folder so that's a good sign.

My question is : Is there something I forgot to do?

Thank you :)

Comment: you will need to use the `-R` flag when applying ownership using chown like so: `sudo chown -R spazmic:spazmic /home/spazmic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the contents from `/etc/skel` to your home directory (and fix the ownership of the copied files afterwards).

Comment: Amazing, I compared with my other VPS and it added the files that weren't there. Apparently those files are the files that goes in the home directory of a newly created user. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `/etc/skel` is for.